# Why submit button is italic?

Tags: html, forms, submit

```
<input type="submit" value="SEA">
```

css

```
input[type="submit"]{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow:-1px 1px #000000;
    line-height:27px;
    background-image:url(backs/01.png);
    border:0;
    border-radius:5px;
    outline:none;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

The text `SEA` is in italic letters. How to set normal letters on the button?

Comment: Did you try it on different browsers?

Comment: @StanimirYakimov, in Firefox is ok. Problem is in Chrome.

Comment: use `font-style:normal !important;` to override any other css might be applied, although using `!important` is not recommended. presumably some other css takes precedence, it is good to use the normalise.css to make sure uniform performance in all browsers

Comment: I don't see it italicized in Chrome or even Firefox!